# Can I pass all variable arguments to a .format() method?

Tags: python

```
x="this" 
y="is" 
z="cake" 
print("{x}{y}{z}".format(z,y,x))
```

The code above gives the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\....\class_var_and_instance_var.py", line 36, in <module>
    print("{x}{y}{z}".format(z,y,x))
KeyError: 'x'
```

Comment: Why not just use f-strings? But you're mixing up positional and keyword arguments, basically.

Comment: `format` has no idea what variable names were used to provide its arguments. You need explicit keyword arguments like `"...".format(x=z, y=y, z=x)` to convey that information.

Comment: Try `print(f"{x}{y}{z}")` instead of `print("{x}{y}{z}".format(z,y,x))`

Comment: So I can pass the keywords only if they are inside the format() method like print("{x}{y}{z}".format(z="hi",y="hello",x="hey"))? not when the variables are set outside

Answer (score 1):

Way 1 : using `.format()`

```
print("{x}-{y}-{z}".format(x=x, y=y, z=z))
```

Way 2: using `f-strings`

```
print(f"{x}{y}{z}")
```

Way 3: using `format(**kwargs)`

```
vars = dict(x="this", y="is", z="cake")
print("{x}-{y}-{z}".format(**vars))
```

Answer (score -1):

This one should work:

```
x="this" 
y="is" 
z="cake" 
print("{x}{y}{z}".format(z=z,y=y,x=x))
```

your code didn't work since format() expects explicit keywords

Comment: Also there's weird trick with `.format(**locals())` =)